# Firebase query returning strange result

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm using Firebase in my app, and I've got a path that includes child nodes with 'linked_timestamp' values of `kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp`. I'm using this code to only return the items that aren't older than 24 hours:

```
Firebase *usersRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://<MY-APP>.firebaseio.com/users"];
Firebase *itemsRef = [usersRef childByAppendingPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/items/", userId]];

double currentTimeSince1970 = (double)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
double epochTime = currentTimeSince1970 * 1000;
double startingAtTimestamp = epochTime - (24 * 3600000);
NSNumber *startingAtTimestampNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:startingAtTimestamp];

FQuery *itemsQuery = [[itemsRef queryOrderedByChild:@"linked_timestamp"] queryStartingAtValue:startingAtTimestampNumber];
[itemsQuery observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    // Downloaded
}];
```

But for some reason, a child node with a way too little value is returned.

[image]

**Any ideas on why?**

**Update**

Firebase structure:

```
{
"items" : {
"-KBOcj7jlWh4wg8WWhyc" : {
    // information
    },
"-KBOcxL4f2-Az4meOLsW" : {
    // information
    }
},
"users" : {
"1117555594922215" : {
  "first_name" : "First name",
  "last_name" : "Last name",
  "items" : {
    "-KBOcj7jlWh4wg8WWhyc" : {
      "linked_timestamp" : "54354"
    },
    "-KBOcxL4f2-Az4meOLsW" : {
      "linked_timestamp" : 1457119545959
    }
  },
  "register_date" : "04-03-2016 18:02"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste your actual Firebase data structure into your question? You can export it to a flat file by using the Export button in the upper right corner of your dashboard.

Comment: @Jay pasted it now, it's somewhat stripped down from the original structure to not spoil the app idea or displays tons of lines - but it displays the structure and data used in the question's query

Comment: ok. well. It's doing what you are asking. If you have 54354 as a value in Firebase then your Firebase query is going to return that value. Looks to me there is some issue with *writing* the values.

Comment: @Jay hmm, not quite sure what you mean here. Wouldn't the `FQuery` limit the results returned to those parent nodes with a child node value (linked_timestamp) > current unix epoch time in milliseconds? - which is as big as 10^12.

Comment: My apologies. I thought you mean the number was too little, i.e. 54354 doesn't have as many digits as the 1457119545959. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that your 54354 is being stored as a *string* instead of a number.

I've made that error a number of times.

If you go into your Firebase dashboard, you can click in the 54354 field and it will have paren's around the number "54354". Remove those and your code will work.